# Calculating sum of two rows in a T-SQL query related to sum of two rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

My SQL query related to sum of two row:

```
t  |  sum of t
1  |     1       |  (1 + 0) = 1   the output of sum of t come like this    
1  |     2       |  (1 + 1) = 2    
1  |     3       |  (2 + 1) = 3
0  |     3       |  (3 + 0) = 3
1  |     4       |  (3 + 1) = 4
```

Comment: any one know how this output will come on ms access

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want a cumulative sum.  This requires having a column that specifies the ordering of the rows in a table.  Remember, a table represents an *unordered* set, so you need a column to specify the ordering.

Assuming you have such a column, in SQL Server 2012+, you can use:

```
select col1, sum(col1) over (order by id)
from t;
```

where `id` is the ordering column.

In earlier versions, you have several options, none of them efficient.  Here is one method using a correlated subquery:

```
select col1,
       (select sum(t2.col1) 
        from t as t2
        where t2.id <= t.id
       ) as cume_sum
from t;
```

Comment: @vinu, well you tagged it as `SQL Server`, so SQL Server query is what you get

Comment: hello if you know how it is possible in ms access query please help

Comment: @vinu . . . The correlated subquery will work in MS Access.